# Can't find file or directory in codeship

Tags: deployment, codeship

I have my own server accessible by SSH that I want to deploy my projects too. I'm using Codeship to automate this process with Git. This is the custom script I'm using within codeship taken from their [documentation] (https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/#continuous-deployment-with-rsync)! :

I've read the documentation and it tells you to put the tilde at the front of the project. But for some reason that isn't working.

```
echo "Deploying"
rsync -avz -e "ssh" ~/mywebsite.co.uk/ 
debian@myserver:/srv/mywebsite.co.uk/
echo "Deployed"

rsync -avz -e "ssh" ~/mywebsite.co.uk/ 
debian@myserver:/srv/mywebsite.co.uk/
00:01
Warning: Permanently added 'myserver' (ECDSA) to the list of 
known hosts.

00:01
sending incremental file list
00:01
rsync: change_dir "/home/rof/mywebsite.co.uk" failed: No 
such file or directory (2)
00:01

00:01
sent 20 bytes  received 12 bytes  21.33 bytes/sec
00:01
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
00:01
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous 
errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

An [ssh debug session](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/ssh-access/) is ideal for troubleshooting this scenario. Reach out to the [CodeShip help desk](http://helpdesk.codeship.com) if you have any questions or concerns with this approach.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline